# How do descendants pass data to parent in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I was curious if a descendant of a descendant of a parent want to pass information back up to the parent would the descendant that is passing the information back need to go through the chain back up.

```
descendant2 Component -> descendant1 Component -> Parent Component
```

This would be the event Emitter  in Descendant 2 Component:

```
@Output() loginStatus: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
formSubmit(){this.loginStatus.emit(true);}
```

In the parent we can just capture that event

```
<registerForm (loginStatus)="setLoginState()"></registerForm>
```

Could we just set up an eventEmitter in descendant2 and bind to that event in Parent Component?

Answer (score 0):

For a clean architecture, you may not want to directly tie descendant 2 to the parent.

So you could generate an event from descendant 2 to descendant 1 to the parent.

Or you could consider using a service to communicate between the family of components.

I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

And here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string;
}
```

This demonstrates communication between two sibling components, but they could easily be parent/child components instead.